# JAXB unmarshal exception cannot find JAXBContextFinder for media type: text/html;charset="UTF-8"

Tags: java, xml, jax-ws

I'm working on a legacy application and I'm getting an exception trying to parse an xml feed. Based on the exception I think it is a missing jar (we're using maven but have had some dependency problems). Google isn't turning up anything useful. Here is the stacktrace:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalException: Could not find JAXBContextFinder for media type: text/html;charset="UTF-8"
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.findJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:49)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.readFrom(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:95)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:398)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:346)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:319)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:114)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:72)
```

Comment: have a look at this http://blog.2partsmagic.com/2009/04/resolving-could-not-find-jaxbcontextfinder-for-media-type-texthtml/ , might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your http user agent is requesting something other than text/html. e.g. application/json. e.g. via ext.ajax.request use

```
Ext.Ajax.request({headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},...)
```

Cause: The method returns an object. If the JAX-RS server needs to return text/html then there would need to be some way to do that. Most JAX-RS servers likely will not have a default object-to-html MessageBodyWriter.

Comment: I'm starting to think that it is returning some kind of error message. Is there any way to print out the response before it goes to the JAXB stuff?